# Passing a value (age) from a widget to another

Tags: flutter, class, datetime, variables

Through textfield inputs, age of user is obtained with the following code (truncated for simplicity):

```
onChanged: (valueYear) {
                          if (valueYear.length == 4)
                            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                          valueYearKey = valueYear;
                          valueBirthKey = valueDayKey +
                              '-' +
                              valueMonthKey +
                              '-' +
                              valueYearKey;
                          print(valueBirthKey);
                          DateTime _dateTime = DateTime(
                            int.parse(valueBirthKey.substring(6)),
                            int.parse(valueBirthKey.substring(3, 5)),
                            int.parse(valueBirthKey.substring(0, 2)),
                          );
                          age = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                                      DateTime.now()
                                          .difference(_dateTime)
                                          .inMilliseconds)
                                  .year -
                              1970;
                          print(age);
                          return age = UserAge.age;
                        })),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the terminal, the age was successfully printed. I then formed a class hoping to store the printed value in this class:

```
class UserAge with ChangeNotifier {
  static int age;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Below is user pressing a button, if age > 18, dialog pops to confirm and proceed, if age < 18, underage, another dialog pops up.

```
 onPressed: () async {
                      if (UserAge.age > 18) {
                        await confirmAgeDialog(context);
                      } else {
                        skipAgeDialog(context);
                      }
```

No red errors was seen on the page, however when I tabbed the button, the error pops up that my UserAge.age is null.

Which leads me to conclude that the age received from the initial printed value wasn't stored successfully to the class. I've been trying to fix it but to no avail. Im new I apologize if the answer is staring me right in the face. Any guidance is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: I wonder where you are assigning value to `UserAge.age` ?

Comment: return age = UserAge.age;
in the first section.

I apologize if this is wrong

Comment: instead of  `age = UserAge.age`  use   `UserAge.age =age `

Comment: Nidheesh, thank you!!! For the year input, the 1994, 1996, 1997, 1998 are not allowed. Meaning I can input the numbers to 199-, but the last number of 4,6,7,8 are not allowed. Any idea why is this so?
I saw that youre from South India, we hope that you and your family are staying safe amidst the recent covid spread. :)

Comment: I didn't get you completely, but from the code it seems to be you are just unfocusing from the field, means you can again edit the formfield.

Comment: i see. Nope the focus is still in the input. However, the numbers 4,6,7,8 just won't appear, no matter how many times I press. Whereas the other numbers can appear for the last digit of the year.

Comment: Please share full code of the form field

Comment: Hey Nidheesh, the question is just posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67553580/how-to-solve-for-number-input-in-textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `age = UserAge.age` use `UserAge.age =age`