# How To Solve For Number Input In TextField?

Tags: flutter, date, input, numbers

Questions:

Inputs for day, month: How does the code only allow for 01, 02, 03 instead of just 1, 2, 3?

Inputs for year: The last digit of the year eg 199() doesn't allow for digits 4,6,7,8, any way to solve it?

I have tried to check several posts but can't find the solution to this.

I apologize if the answer is staring me right in the face. Pretty new to this.

```
FocusNode textSecondFocusNode = new FocusNode();

TextFormField textSecond = new TextFormField(
  focusNode: textSecondFocusNode,
);

class _BumbleState extends State<Bumble> {
  final myControllerDay = TextEditingController();
  final myControllerMonth = TextEditingController();
  final myControllerYear = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    myControllerDay.dispose();
    myControllerMonth.dispose();
    myControllerYear.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  var age = UserAge.age;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
    child: rowOfBirthdateInput(
                myControllerDay: myControllerDay,
                myControllerMonth: myControllerMonth,
                myControllerYear: myControllerYear),
         
        )); 
  }
}




class rowOfBirthdateInput extends StatelessWidget {
  rowOfBirthdateInput({
    Key key,
    @required this.myControllerDay,
    @required this.myControllerMonth,
    @required this.myControllerYear,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController myControllerDay;
  final TextEditingController myControllerMonth;
  final TextEditingController myControllerYear;

  var valueDayKey;
  var valueMonthKey;
  var valueYearKey;
  var valueBirthKey;

  static int age;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    (TEXTFIELD DECORATION...)
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        maxLength: 2,
                        controller: myControllerDay,
                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[1-31]')),
                        ],
                        onChanged: (valueDay) {
                          if (valueDay.length == 2)
                            FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                          valueDayKey = valueDay;
                          print(valueDayKey);
                        })),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                  (TEXTFIELD DECORATION...)

                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        maxLength: 2,
                        controller: myControllerMonth,
                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                              RegExp(r'[1 - 12]')),
                        ],
                        onChanged: (valueMonth) {
                          if (valueMonth.length == 2)
                            FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                          valueMonthKey = valueMonth;
                          print(valueMonthKey);
                        })),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                  (TEXTFIELD DECORATION...)

                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                              RegExp(r'[1952 - 2003]')),
                        ],
                        maxLength: 4,
                        controller: myControllerYear,
                        onChanged: (valueYear) {
                          if (valueYear.length == 4)
                            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                          valueYearKey = valueYear;
                          valueBirthKey = valueDayKey +
                              '-' +
                              valueMonthKey +
                              '-' +
                              valueYearKey;
                          print(valueBirthKey);
                          DateTime _dateTime = DateTime(
                            int.parse(valueBirthKey.substring(6)),
                            int.parse(valueBirthKey.substring(3, 5)),
                            int.parse(valueBirthKey.substring(0, 2)),
                          );
                          age = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                                      DateTime.now()
                                          .difference(_dateTime)
                                          .inMilliseconds)
                                  .year -
                              1970;
                          print(age);
                          return UserAge.age = age;
                        })),
               
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserAge with ChangeNotifier {
  static int age;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Comment: you are using regex, that is why you can't enter 4,6,7,8 numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex expression used in the TextFormField is limiting 4,6,7,8 in the year fields

Regex for allowing 0-12 will

`FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'\d[1-2]*$')),`

you can validate the entered value either in `onChanged` callback or `onSaved` callback of the text form field. or you can use the `datepicker` to choose the date.

```
selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
  final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
      firstDate: DateTime(1952),
      lastDate: DateTime(2003));
  if (picked != null)
    setState(() {
      selectedDate = picked;
      _dateController.text = DateFormat.yMd().format(selectedDate);
    });
}
```

There you can give the initial and last date to be picked.

you can find the more info of date picker [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html)

Comment: Once again, thanks Nidheesh. =)

But let's say if I were to use a datepicker for simplicity, is there a way to show the datepicker automatically when the page is shown? Instead of clicking a button and only then calling for the function of datepicker.

Comment: You can use it in the initstate of the statefull widget